# react-textfit not installing properly

Tags: npm, terminal, command-line

I am trying to do npm

```
npm i react-textfit
```

for my calculator app, but for some reason this doesn't work.

[image: This is the what the terminal returns when I run the command]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same problem a few days back
Check for the following

- Are the other dependencies installed using Yarn, if yes run the same command with `yarn add react-textfit`
- Delete the package.json or the yarn.lock file along with the node_modules and install everything again using `yarn`
- If it is still not fixed using the `--force` flag at the end of your install command

Comment: How would I used `yarn` to install everything again? Sorry I am new

Comment: in your project do you have a package.lock.json or a yarn.lock file?

Comment: did you try the command `yarn add react-textfit`

Comment: I don't have a yarn.lock file but I do have a pack-lock.json file

Comment: delete that, node_modules and then run `npm install`

Comment: also if possible can you share the git repo?